# jQuery UI sortable and container zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zooming, drag

I want to sort divs within a container that has a zoom of 0.4;

The problem is that when i drag the elements to sort them, the position of the dragged div is not relative to the mouse cursor. How can I have the divs move relative to the cursor as if the container didnt have zoom:0.4?

Heres a demo. Simply drag an element and you will see that the div does not movie according to the cursor. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CFfxb

```
#container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
  background-color:red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  zoom: 0.4;
}
```

Comment: Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just update the position on your own.

If you have the CSS:

```
#container{
    zoom: 0.5;
}
```

You would use:

```
$('#container').sortable(
    drag: function(e,ui){
        zoomAmount = 2;
        ui.position.top = (e.clientY + $("body").scrollTop()) * zoomAmount;
        ui.position.left = e.clientX * zoomAmount;
    }
);
```

You'll have to update the zoomAmount variable to match the zoom factor you're using.

So for:

```
zoom:0.4
```

You would change it to:

```
zoomAmount = 2.2;
```